# Collection of unique SelectListitems from list of non-unique SelectListitems using linq

Tags: linq

I am having the hardest time coming up with a methodology to take a list of non-unique Selectlistitems and come out with a list of unique SelectListItems.  I am attempting to use linq to do this... The code for what I tried was this

```
    var queryResults =
    from p in PatientList
    group p by p.Value into g
    select new SelectListItem { Text= g.Key, Value= g.Max(p => p.Value.Split('|')[1]) };
```

With this methodology I get the exact same list that I went in with.  Now I am a complete novice when it comes to linq.  I have done some linq to XML and linq to SQL, but Linq to Collections seems to be alluding...

Any Help possible?

Comment: You may find this question of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)? It returns unique values from a sequence, optionally using an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the uniqueness test.

Comment: I didn't think of that.  Let me give that a try.

Comment: As far as I know, Distinct() will check the hash code on the objects in the collection and filter based on that. If the duplicate SelectListItems in the collection are not actually the same objects but other objects that just look the same you'll find you end up with the same list.

Comment: MoreLinq (http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) provides a DistinctBy method in which you can pass a comparison lambda: items.DistinctBy(c => c.Value)

Comment: I am not to sure how that would help me.  This appears to be an intractable problem.