# Removing lines that contain the same thing in a list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a list that contains something like this:

```
C12 0402 123456 90
C133 0402 123456 90
C9 0402 123456 90
C132 0603 abcd 0
C54 0603 abcd 0
R FID1 fiducial 0
R FID2 fiducial 0
R FID3 fiducial 0
R FID4 fiducial 0
```

I would like to check each line in the List and make sure that the duplicates are not added... I tried this but I know there is a logic error in here.

```
List<string> noDuplicatesList = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in theList)
{
    if (!noDuplicatesList.Contains(line.PartNumber)) //This is doing nothing...?
        noDuplicatesList.Add(line.Name + " " + line.PartDescription + " " line.PartNumber + " " + line.Rotation);
}

foreach (var line in noDuplicatesList)
{
    var splitLine = line.Split(' ');
    //Print out statements...
}
```

### Question

How do I remove/skip lines that contain the same value (in the example above `123456`, `abcd`, `fiducial`) so that it will only print something like this:

```
C12 0402 123456 90
C132 0603 abcd 0
R FID1 fiducial 0
```

Comment: Will duplicates always be grouped together like in the example? Or could a line with e.g. "123456" also appear later in the list?

Comment: @dario: no, that's just removing basic duplicate lines. This is removing lines with duplicate tokens... very different.

Comment: @Charles: They wil lbe grouped together.

Comment: @Charles: My bad. Anyway, I think LINQ's the way to go here

Comment: Do all lines always have exactly 4 columns?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda for an idea, specifically Jon Skeet's answer (DistinctBy)

Comment: @Charles: Yes they will all have 4 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just use the 3rd column as the grouping condition?

```
var noDuplicatesList = lines
    .GroupBy(l => l.PartNumber)
    .Select(group => group.First())

foreach(var item in noDuplicatesList)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", 
        item.Name,
        item.PartDescription,
        item.PartNumber,
        item.Rotation
    );
```

---

`lines:`

```
C12 0402 123456 90
C133 0402 123456 90
C9 0402 123456 90
C132 0603 abcd 0
C54 0603 abcd 0
R FID1 fiducial 0
R FID2 fiducial 0
R FID3 fiducial 0
R FID4 fiducial 0
```

`lines.GroupBy(l => l.PartNumber):`

```
{ C12 0402 123456 90, C133 0402 123456 90, C9 0402 123456 90}
{ C132 0603 abcd 0, C54 0603 abcd 0 }
{ R FID1 fiducial 0, R FID2 fiducial 0, R FID3 fiducial 0, R FID4 fiducial 0 }
```

`lines.GroupBy(l => l.PartNumber).Select(group => group.First()):`

```
C12 0402 123456 90
C132 0603 abcd 0
R FID1 fiducial 0
```

Comment: okay, just editted the code to make it a bit more explanatory.

Comment: Wow that's great! Thank you for the breakdown of what it looks like too. I never knew what the `GroupBy` looked like :)

Answer (score 0):

(On reflection, this answer is assuming that order counts in your list.  If order doesn't matter, then just use `GroupBy` as cited in the answer below.)

The typical "modular" way to accomplish this would be to write a `PartitionBy` function that works something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<ICollection<T>> PartitionBy<T, U>(
    IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, U> selector)
{
    var buffer = new List<T>();

    using (var e = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var priorValue = selector(e.Current);
        buffer.Add(e.Current);

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            var newValue = selector(e.Current);

            if (!object.Equals(selector(e.Current), priorValue))
            {
                priorValue = newValue;
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = new List<T>();
            }

            buffer.Add(e.Current);
        }
    }

    if (buffer.Any())
        yield return buffer;
}
```

Then your problem can be solved like this:

```
var results = PartitionBy(objs, x => /* ... */).Select(list => list.First());
```

where the `...` are however you get the third value out of an object in your list (e.g. `x.Split()[2]`.)