# Why is there no Overload of Distinct() accepting a Comparison Delegate (or similar)

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, distinct, iequalitycomparer

When using the query operator Distinct() the types in the queried sequence must either provide suitable overloads of GetHashCode() and Equals() or you have to pass an implementation of IEqualityComparer<T>.

My question: Why is there no overload of Distinct() accepting a Delegate instance (e.g. Comparison<T>)? - If it was existent a more lighweight lambda expression could be passed (more lightweight than an implementation of IEqualityComparer<T>). - Am I missing something here?

Comment: Distinct will check both Equals and GetHashCode if it must... how lightweight of a lambda do you think you'll actually be able to provide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct() with lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda)

Comment: Hi ErOx! 
I suggested a solution like Tor Haugen proposed in Distinct() with lambda?:
 var distinctValues
    = myCustomerList.Distinct((c1, c2) => c1.CustomerId == c2.CustomerId);

Hi Magnus!
Hm I didn't find Tor's question, so mine is a duplicate, yes!

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: But that only works if the only thing you want to consider is a single property... which is not typically what someone will want. If that is what you want, however, then I would say Jon Skeet's answer and implementation is the way to go (i.e., DistinctBy(x => x.PropertyName)

Comment: Yes, I know Jon's DistinctBy(), maybe the real question is, why this is not existent as standard query operator (paraphrasing SLaks' answer). But often you want to compare a single item (I think, this _is_ a typical case.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it uses `GetHashCode()`.
You cannot make a delegate that gives hash codes.

It could take two delegates, but that would be confusing.

It would be better to ask why there isn't a `DistinctBy()` method that takes a projection.

Answer (score 1):

otherwise you can try [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and its method DistincBy

Comment: DistinctBy() will be added with .NET 6.