# LINQ - Distinct by value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Code :

```
news = (from New myNew in new News()
       select myNew).Distinct().ToList();
```

but this Distinct is for "object" with same values. I need, into my list, a `myNew` for each month. (so one for january, one for februaru, and so on). Than, `news` will get 12 record.

Is it possible a sort of `Distinct(myNew.Month)`?

Comment: If you have multiple records for a month, how do you want decide which one to take? The first one perhaps?

Comment: Is `News` a collection of `New` elements?

Comment: @Danny there's no overload of Distinct that takes a lambda

Comment: Well, the answer to the question I added gives myCustomerList.GroupBy(cust => cust.CustomerId).Select(grp => grp.First());

Comment: @Perception: This answer is not a duplicate at all from ["Distinct() with lambda?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda) as you can see easily from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10514121/284240).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could group by month and take the first or last or whatever(you haven't told us):

```
var news = News()
           .GroupBy(n => n.Month)
           .Select(grp => grp.Last());
```

**Edit**: From the comment on Habib's answer i see that you want 12 months even if there are no news. Then you need to do a "Linq Outer-Join":

```
var monthlyNews = from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12) // left outer join every month
                  join n in News() on m equals n.Month into m_n
                  from n in m_n.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  group n by m into MonthGroups
                  select new {
                      Month = MonthGroups.Key, 
                      LastNews = MonthGroups.Last() 
                  };
foreach (var m in monthlyNews)
{
    int month = m.Month;
    var lastNewsInMonth = m.LastNews;
    if (lastNewsInMonth != null) ; // do something...
}
```

**Edit**: Since you have problems to implement the query in your code, you don't need to select the anonymous type which contains also the month. You can also select only the  news itself:

```
var monthlyNews = from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12) // every motnh
                  join n in news on m equals n.Month into m_n
                  from n in m_n.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  group n by m into MonthGroups
                  select MonthGroups.Last();
```

Note that you now get 12 news but some of them might be `null` when there are no news in that month.

Comment: Why post the answer after this has been marked as a duplicate with the exact same answer?

Comment: @DannyVarod: Because 1. it's not exact the same answer(btw,i haven't seen that answer before) 2. both question might differ more from each other if OP would clarify his requirement.

Comment: @DannyVarod: Is it better now? ;-)

Comment: The problem here is that News() is a List<New>... seems I can't write your code...

Comment: @markzzz: So what's the problem? When `News` is a `List<New>` write `...join n in News on m equals n.Month into m_n...`.

Comment: But this create a list of pair value (Month, LastNews). I need to create a list of (just) New into "monthlyNews" (which is a List<New>)

Comment: You can easily change the query to select not the anonymous type with the month but only the news itself. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You rock as well! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1. Get [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (also available as NuGet package and use

```
  News().DistinctBy(n => n.Property)
```

Solution 2. Implement an [IEqualityComparer and use this Distinct() overload.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
var result  =  News()
  .GroupBy(p => p.Month)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: the problem is : if the april doesnt exist in any new...how can I insert "null" instead?

Answer (score 2):

Short hand solution

```
var vNews  =  News()   
              .GroupBy(p => p.Month, (key, p) => p.FirstOrDefault()) 
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vNews  =  News()   
              .GroupBy(p => p.Month)   
              .Select(g => g.First())   
              .ToList();
```