# LINQ Getting Unique items from a List within a List

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable, distinct

I have a `List` of type `MyObject` with a definition below:

```
class MyObject {
     public string ListName { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<OtherObject> ObjectList { get; set;}
}
```

Given a `List` of type `MyObject`, using LINQ what expression should I use to get all distinct `OtherObject`?

What I was planning to do was loop each `MyObject` and get the distinct `OtherObject` from the `ObjectList` property, but then I need to get the distinct across the list.

Please note that if:
   `MyObject[0].Objectlist[0] == 'ItemA'` and `MyObject[1].Objectlist[0] == 'ItemA'` it will still return a single instance of `ItemA`. This code is just a representation only. This is not how I access my objects, by the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda might this be something worth looking at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this simply using [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) logic. C# has a nice implementation in the form of [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var set = new HashSet<OtherObject>(myObjects.SelectMany(mo => mo.ObjectList));
```

Or if you prefer deferred execution, you can use the LINQ [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var distinct = myObjects.SelectMany(mo => mo.ObjectList).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have an object that is a property of a bigger object, that is in a list, that is in a list. Was able to get a unique list by doing `data.SelectMany(d => d.Refs).Select(r => r.MyObject).Distinct()` which is way simpler than using a `.ForEach()`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var l = new List<MyObject>(...);
var unique = l.SelectMany(j => j.ObjectList).Distinct();
```

You can use the technique from [Distinct() with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda) to alter how you decide if an object is distinct from another.