# Get list of distinct values in List<T> in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, distinct

So, say I have something like the following:

```
public class Element
{
  public int ID;
  public int Type;
  public Properties prorerty;
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class Properties
{
  public int Id;
  public string Property;
  ...
}
```

and I have a list of these:

```
List Elements = new List();
```

What would be the cleanest way to get a list of all distinct values in the prorerty column in Element class? I mean, I could iterate through the list and add all values that aren't duplicates to another list of strings, but this seems dirty and inefficient. I have a feeling there's some magical Linq construction that'll do this in one line, but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447766/linq-getting-unique-items-from-a-list-within-a-list

Comment: You don't you rather use set

Answer (score 8):

```
 var results = Elements.Distinct();
```

Note: you will have to override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode()`

```
public class Element : IEqualityComparer<Element>
{
   public bool Equals(Element x, Element y)
   {
     if (x.ID == y.ID)
     {
        return true;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
}

public int GetHashCode(Element obj)
{
    return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Or pass a custom `IEqualityComparer`. :)

Comment: To me it sounds like he just wants a collections of string. He can use a predefined equality comparer for `System.String` for that.

Comment: Implementing `IEqualityComparer<Element>` in Element is quite unusual. Either create an `ElementComparer` class or implement `IComparable<Element>` in Element.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't simpler to use one of the approaches shown below :) ? You can just group your domain objects by some key and select FirstOrDefault like below.
This is a copy of my answer on similar question here:
[Get unique values - original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539193/get-distinct-list-values/37653582#37653582)

More interesting option is to create some Comparer adapter that takes you domain object and creates other object the Comparer can use/work with out of the box. Base on the comparer you can create your custom linq extensions like in sample below. Hope it helps :)

```
[TestMethod]
public void CustomDistinctTest()
{
    // Generate some sample of domain objects
    var listOfDomainObjects = Enumerable
                                .Range(10, 10)
                                .SelectMany(x => 
                                    Enumerable
                                    .Range(15, 10)
                                    .Select(y => new SomeClass { SomeText = x.ToString(), SomeInt = x + y }))
                                .ToList();

    var uniqueStringsByUsingGroupBy = listOfDomainObjects
                                    .GroupBy(x => x.SomeText)
                                    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                                    .ToList();

    var uniqueStringsByCustomExtension = listOfDomainObjects.DistinctBy(x => x.SomeText).ToList();
    var uniqueIntsByCustomExtension = listOfDomainObjects.DistinctBy(x => x.SomeInt).ToList();

    var uniqueStrings = listOfDomainObjects
                            .Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<SomeClass, string>(x => x.SomeText))
                            .OrderBy(x=>x.SomeText)
                            .ToList();

    var uniqueInts = listOfDomainObjects
                            .Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<SomeClass, int>(x => x.SomeInt))
                            .OrderBy(x => x.SomeInt)
                            .ToList();
}
```

Custom comparer adapter:

```
public class EqualityComparerAdapter<T, V> : EqualityComparer<T>
    where V : IEquatable<V>
{
    private Func<T, V> _valueAdapter;

    public EqualityComparerAdapter(Func<T, V> valueAdapter)
    {
        _valueAdapter = valueAdapter;
    }

    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _valueAdapter(x).Equals(_valueAdapter(y));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _valueAdapter(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Custom linq extension (definition of DistinctBy extension method):

```
// Embed this class in some specific custom namespace
public static class DistByExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T,V>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerator,Func<T,V> valueAdapter)
        where V : IEquatable<V>
    {
        return enumerator.Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<T, V>(valueAdapter));
    }
}
```

Definition of domain class used in test case:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: GroupBy(x => x.SomeText).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(); Worked out for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var props = Elements.Select(x => x.Properties).Distinct();
```

And make sure you overridden `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` methods.
Or if you need direct strings from `Properties`:

```
var props = Elements
    .Select(x => x.Properties != null ? x.Properties.Property : null)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the string fields on the `Properties` field, and if you know the `Properties` field `prorerty` is never `null`, just use

```
IEnumerable<string> uniqueStrings = Elements
  .Select(e => e.prorerty.Property).Distinct();
```

If there's a chance `prorerty` can be null, handle that situation in the lambda.

This will use the default equality comparer for `String` which is an *ordinal* comparison independent of culture and case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

my working example from LINQPad (C# Program)

```
void Main()
{
    var ret = new List<Element>();
    ret.Add(new Element(){ID=1});
    ret.Add(new Element(){ID=1});
    ret.Add(new Element(){ID=2});
    ret = ret.GroupBy(x=>x.ID).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ret.Count()); // shows 2
}

public class Element
{
  public int ID;
  public int Type;
  public Properties prorerty; 
}

public class Properties
{
  public int Id;
  public string Property;

}
```