# Get distinct list values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have a C# application in which i'd like to get from a `List` of **Project** objects , another List which contains distinct objects.

i tried this

```
 List<Project> model = notre_admin.Get_List_Project_By_Expert(u.Id_user);
 if (model != null) model = model.Distinct().ToList();
```

The list model still contains 4 identical objects `Project`.

What is the reason of this? How can i fix it?

Comment: is distinct in list actually works on OBJECTS ??

Comment: Define "identical" in this context.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you explain more plz

Comment: You will need to supply an EqualityComparer. See the overloads list for Distinct().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define "identical" here. I'm guessing you mean "have the same contents", but that **is not** the default definition for classes: the default definition is "are the same instance".

If you want "identical" to mean "have the same contents", you have two options:

- write a custom comparer (`IEqualityComparer<Project>`) and supply that as a parameter to `Distinct`
- override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `Project`

There are also custom methods like `DistinctBy` that are available lots of places, which is useful if identity can be determined by a single property (`Id`, typically) - not in the BCL, though. But for example:

```
if (model != null) model = model.DistinctBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

With, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<TItem>
    DistinctBy<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items,
    Func<TItem, TValue> selector)
{
    var uniques = new HashSet<TValue>();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if(uniques.Add(selector(item))) yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var newList = 
(
from x in model
select new {Id_user= x.Id_user}
).Distinct();
```

or you can write like this

```
var list1 = model.DistinctBy(x=> x.Id_user);
```

Comment: The first changes the result - it gives you the ids, not the projects; the second is not a standard method.

Answer (score 5):

How do you define identical? You should override `Equals` in `Project` with this definition (if you override `Equals` also override `GetHashCode`). For example:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p2 = obj as Project;
        if (p2 == null) return false;
        return this.ProjectID == m2.ProjectID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ProjectID;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are just checking [reference equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Comment: By this, I *think* @Henk means "the equality / hash should be appropriate for your type's definition of equality, which may ***or may not*** be limited to just one property like the `ProjectId`"

Comment: @MarcGravell: I don't know OP's `Project` class so i've presumed something db-related which has an identifier like `...Id`. Why should i complicate things before OP has clarified his definition of _identical_?

Comment: What @MarcGravell said, plus Equality should not be overridden for mutable objects. The ProjectID is probably logically immutable, making this example just acceptable. But add a Name property and it'll end in tears.

Comment: @Henk indeed, mutability and dictionaries (etc) that span more than a single snapshot of time are a recipe for pain.

Comment: But it may also be desired to find projects (in a list or dictionary) via ID even if a name was changed. So why must **all** properties be identical to identify an object? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No, all identifying properties should be immutable. The OP just isn't clear about this. But changing Equality has project-wide consequences, a simple Comparer is what's asked for here.

Answer (score 4):

The object's reference aren't equal. If you want to be able to do that on the entire object itself and not just a property, you have to implement the IEqualityComparer or IEquatable<T>.

Answer (score 3):

Check this example: you need to use either Comparator or override `Equals()`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add( new Item( "A" ) );
        items.Add( new Item( "A" ) );
        items.Add( new Item( "B" ) );
        items.Add( new Item( "C" ) );

        items = items.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    public Item( string name )
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals( object obj )
    {
        return Name.Equals((obj as Item).Name);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's [**an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects/1365761#1365761) from basically the same question that will help.

Explanation:

> The Distinct() method checks reference equality for reference types. This means it is looking for literally the same object duplicated, not different objects which contain the same values.

Credits to @Rex M.

Comment: This isn't correct, though; the `Distinct()` method (without a custom equality comparer) **simply applies that type's own definition of equality**. It is the *type* that determines the meaning of equality, not `Distinct()`

Comment: Didn't think of it that way. :) I just found the answer where he uses the custom comparer and I figured this was exact what he was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't simpler to use one of the approaches shown below :) ?
You can just group your domain objects by some key and select FirstOrDefault like below.

More interesting option is to create some Comparer adapter that takes you domain object and creates other object the Comparer can use/work with out of the box. Base on the comparer you can create your custom linq extensions like in sample below. Hope it helps :)

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CustomDistinctTest()
    {
        // Generate some sample of domain objects
        var listOfDomainObjects = Enumerable
                                    .Range(10, 10)
                                    .SelectMany(x => 
                                        Enumerable
                                        .Range(15, 10)
                                        .Select(y => new SomeClass { SomeText = x.ToString(), SomeInt = x + y }))
                                    .ToList();

        var uniqueStringsByUsingGroupBy = listOfDomainObjects
                                        .GroupBy(x => x.SomeText)
                                        .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                                        .ToList();

        var uniqueStringsByCustomExtension = listOfDomainObjects.DistinctBy(x => x.SomeText).ToList();
        var uniqueIntsByCustomExtension = listOfDomainObjects.DistinctBy(x => x.SomeInt).ToList();

        var uniqueStrings = listOfDomainObjects
                                .Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<SomeClass, string>(x => x.SomeText))
                                .OrderBy(x=>x.SomeText)
                                .ToList();

        var uniqueInts = listOfDomainObjects
                                .Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<SomeClass, int>(x => x.SomeInt))
                                .OrderBy(x => x.SomeInt)
                                .ToList();
    }
```

Custom comparer adapter:

```
public class EqualityComparerAdapter<T, V> : EqualityComparer<T>
    where V : IEquatable<V>
{
    private Func<T, V> _valueAdapter;

    public EqualityComparerAdapter(Func<T, V> valueAdapter)
    {
        _valueAdapter = valueAdapter;
    }

    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _valueAdapter(x).Equals(_valueAdapter(y));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _valueAdapter(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Custom linq extension (definition of DistinctBy extension method):

```
// Embedd this class in some specific custom namespace
public static class DistByExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T,V>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerator,Func<T,V> valueAdapter)
        where V : IEquatable<V>
    {
        return enumerator.Distinct(new EqualityComparerAdapter<T, V>(valueAdapter));
    }
}
```

Definition of domain object used in test case:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ViewClReceive> passData = (List<ViewClReceive>)TempData["passData_Select_BankName_List"];
    passData = passData?.DistinctBy(b=>b.BankNm).ToList();
```

It will Works ......