# How to select a record in a arraylist vb.net linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

`Dim objLab As New ArrayList`

objLab has 300 list of names and i want to select if the name is Telkom but its returning null record. I have tried to seahch some solution on stack with no luck.

This is what i tried `Dim labQuery = From Laboratory In objLab Where Laboratory.Name = "Telkom" Select Laboratory`

code that i tried also:
[vb.net LINQ select Distinct to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548596/vb-net-linq-select-distinct-to-a-list)

[How to select last record in a LINQ GroupBy clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304710/how-to-select-last-record-in-a-linq-groupby-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
Dim objLab As New ArrayList
objLab.Add("Abc")
objLab.Add("Telkom")
objLab.Add("StackOverFlow")

Dim labQuery = From item In objLab
               Where item.Equals("Telkom")
               Select item

Console.WriteLine("Results :")
For Each s In labQuery
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

… OR

```
Dim objLab As New ArrayList From {
    New Labaratory(3, "Abc"),
    New Labaratory(2, "Telkom"),
    New Labaratory(3, "StackOverFlow")
}

Dim labQuery = From item As Labaratory In objLab
               Where item.Name.Equals("Telkom")
               Select item

Console.WriteLine("Results :")
For Each s In labQuery
    Console.WriteLine($"{s.Id} {s.Name}")
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

You can define the class Labaratory as shown below

```
Public Class Labaratory
    Public Sub New(i As Integer, n As String)
        Id = i
        Name = n
    End Sub
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```