# Distinct in Linq based on only one field of the table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to use .distinct in Linq to get result based on one field of the table (so do not require a whole duplicated records from table).

I know writing basic query using distinct as followed:

```
var query = (from r in table1
orderby r.Text
select r).distinct();
```

but I need results where `r.text` is not duplicated.

Comment: You need to specify what field you want to be distinct ,see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Try this:

```
table1.GroupBy(x => x.Text).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

This will group the table by `Text` and use the first row from each groups resulting in rows where `Text` is distinct.

Comment: What if groupby has more than 1 field?

Comment: @user585440: In that case, you use an anonymous type like so: `table1.GroupBy(x => new { x.Text, x.Property2, x.Property3 }).Select(x => x.First());`

Comment: Yes, you are right and I already found it. Thanks anyway. And I also find that Select(x => x.First()) can cause crash. It is better to change to Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @user585440: In that particular scenario, `First` will never cause an exception, because it takes the first item of each group. And there only is a group, if there is at least one item in it.

Comment: I had to use FirstOrDefault or else there was a runtime error

Comment: @TruthOf42 That's rather unlikely. `GroupBy` doesn't create empty groups, see my previous comment. Most likely, your code contains more than what you see here. Maybe you have a `Where` as well or a condition for the `First`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `FirstOrDefault` is mandatory if you are querying a database, even if the groups cannot be empty.

Comment: @edc65 what makes you say that?

Comment: My previuos experience makes me say that, but to be sure I tried with Linqpad using Linq To Entitities and framework 4.5. Is it perhaps different with 6.0?

Comment: @edc65 maybe it was a special scenario where you had to use it in the past?

Comment: @edc65 I may have misunderstood your previous comment. So you could verify in LinqPad that FirstOrDefault is not working? What is happening if you use it?

Comment: (I can't go in chat, it's blocked by my firewall). I'm saying that `FirstOrDefault` **does work**. Instead you used `First` in your answer and `First` does not work and you get a runtime error `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead`. I can't be more clear than that.

Comment: I'm curious under what circumstances we need to use *.FirstOrDefault()* instead of the unsafe *.First()*. If we're grouping by some key, isn't it already implied that no group can be empty? I'm figuring, if there's no elements corresponding to a certain key, then the key won't be in the set of keys of the grouping, will it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: It seems to be or have been a limitation in Entity Framework.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Interesting. **Evil** me: "right, somone ducked up and blames EF". **Humble** me: "well, weirder things have happened...". I'm too lazy to try it out at the moment so I take your word for it. At any rate - strange that deafult suffix would be needed. Might have been some glitch in previous versions that I was lucky not to hit my toe on.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Just read the other comments on this answer. It shows that I thought the same as you did

Answer (score 40):

MoreLinq has a [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=f4c39a771d712a568467eaa31840cc22e07a5ed0) method that you can use:

It will allow you to do:

```
var results = table1.DistictBy(row => row.Text);
```

The implementation of the method (short of argument validation) is as follows:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I wasnt keen to use equalityComparer.

Comment: @MeghaJain Well, one will be used regardless, as `GroupBy` needs one as well.  Both methods will use the default `EqualityComparer` if none is provided.

Comment: Well, correct me if I am wrong, but this distinct here is done in memory, not in DB ? Couldn't this lead to undesired full-scan ?

Comment: @Kek.  No, because of the yield return, you will stop at the first distinct element.  Eventually, yes, you will load each key into the HashSet, but since it's IEnumerable in and IEnumerable out, you will only get those items.

If you are talking about LINQ to SQL, then yes, this will do a table scan.

Answer (score 16):

> but I need results where r.text is not duplicated

Sounds as if you want this:

```
table1.GroupBy(x => x.Text)
      .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
      .Select(g => g.First());
```

This will select rows where the `Text` is unique.

Answer (score 13):

[Daniel Hilgarth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572644/daniel-hilgarth)'s answer above leads to a `System.NotSupported` exception With **Entity-Framework**. With **Entity-Framework**, it has to be:

```
table1.GroupBy(x => x.Text).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 7):

### Update

As of .NET 6 a new [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) operator has been introduced. However, while this works well for Linq to Objects, it doesn't appear to be working for Linq to Entities. I tested it with EF Core 6.0.6 and SQL server.

Generally speaking, LINQ operators come in pairs to support those two scenarios. For example, [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) covers Linq to Objects, [Queryable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select?view=net-6.0) covers Linq to Entities.

Interestingly `DistinctBy` has both of those flavors as well, but EF Core's SQL Server provider doesn't support it's translation to SQL. The reason, in my opinion, is that it would result in a slow query.

### Original Answer

There are lots of discussions around this topic.

You can find one of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda):

One of the most popular suggestions have been the Distinct method taking a lambda expression as a parameter as @Servy has pointed out.

The chief architect of C#, Anders Hejlsberg has suggested the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6834054e-e1c1-49db-970c-370a9012c675). Also explaining why the framework design team decided not to add an overload of Distinct method which takes a lambda.

Answer (score 4):

From what I have found, your query is mostly correct.  Just change "select r" to "select r.Text" is all and that should solve the problem.  This is how MSDN documented how it should work.

Ex:

```
    var query = (from r in table1 orderby r.Text select r.Text).distinct();
```

Comment: you changed the "select" statement that may not be desired in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
data.Select(x=>x.Name).Distinct().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct return you SINGLE column, if that's your case then!!

```
CountryData.Select(x=>x.COUNTRY_NAME).Distinct()
```

Else if you need multiple columns distinct by one column. you need to **groupby** first then select the first item from the group.
*(in this case the rest items in group with different values will not be returned)*

```
CountryData.GroupBy(a=>a.COUNTRY_NAME).Select(a=>a.First());
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code :

```
table1.GroupBy(x => x.Text).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score -6):

You can try this:`table1.GroupBy(t => t.Text).Select(shape => shape.r)).Distinct();`