# MVC EF LINQ - Distinct not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query expecting to retrieve only unique values from the entity according the selected School:

```
var semesters = (from cou in db.Courses
    join sem in db.Semesters on cou.SemesterID equals sem.ID
    where cou.FacultyID == id 
    select new SemestersModel {
        SemesterID = sem.ID,
        SemesterText = sem.Semester })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

However it returns all semesters contained in the entity Courses

- Semester 1,  Semester 1,  Semester 1, Semester 2, Semester 2  ...etc.
  etc.

Please help me to grab only distinct semester names e.g.

- Semester 1,  Semester 2,  etc.

P.S. my issue is different than this one [Distinct in Linq based on only one field of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321013/distinct-in-linq-based-on-only-one-field-of-the-table)

Comment: You calling disctinct on the ID **and** Text not just the text

Comment: Nah it's not a duplicate i checked them all and none of those addresses my issue. Thank you for the input though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group your semesters by the field you want to distinct by, then select the first of the group, now you can project the result into SemestersModel instances.

```
(from cou in db.Courses
    join sem in db.Semesters on cou.SemesterID equals sem.ID
    where cou.FacultyID == id 
    select sem)
    .GroupBy(sem => sem.Semester)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(sem => new SemestersModel {
        SemesterID = sem.ID,
        SemesterText = sem.Semester 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Additional information: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: @ElizabethDimova That change should be fine. I updated my answer. In this case `FirstOrDefault` won't be returning `null` though, so we can forgo any null check.

Comment: Yep. It worked like a charm this time. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Distinct` after you've created `SemestersModel`, if that type doesn't override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` only references are compared, they are different in this case.

So either override these methods, provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<SemestersModel>`(not supported in `Linq-To-Entities` or `Linq-To-Sql`) for `Distinct` or simply use `Distinct` before on an anonymous type:

```
var semesters = from cou in db.Courses
                join sem in db.Semesters 
                on cou.SemesterID equals sem.ID
                where cou.FacultyID == id 
                select new { SemesterID = sem.ID, SemesterText = sem.Semester };
List<SemestersModel> uniqueSemesterList = semesters
    .Distinct()   
    .Select(x => new SemestersModel {
        SemesterID = x.SemesterID, 
        SemesterText = x.SemesterText })
    .ToList(); // due to deferred execution only now the query above will be executed together with Distinct
```

This query can be translated to valid SQL(omitting the `join` and `where`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SemesterID, SemesterText FROM dbo.Semesters
```

The query will be executed and the unique `SemestersModel` instances will be created in memory to fill the list.

Comment: Tim, so is projecting to a named type the equivalent of `AsEnumerable`?

Comment: So, given that this all happens in SQL, is a projected named type treated differently from an anonymous type?

Comment: @spender: the anonymous type can be translated to sql whereas the distinct after the type initialization will compare references. In sql: `SELECT DISTINCT SemesterID, SemesterText FROM dbo.TableName`. But i must admit that i'm not 100% sure how Linq-To-Entities will treat the `Distinct` after the object initialization. I guess it's ignored in sql and will really be applied in memory.

Comment: I'm glad you understood my slightly oblique line of questioning. Might do some experiments later. You've pinpointed something I don't quite understand here.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct method use `IEqualityComparer` to compare the objects. So if you are filtering the records using `Distinct()` you can create a comparer implementing `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to `Distinct()`

Here is a example.

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

class EmpEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        if (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        int hCode = obj.Id;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can test it.

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket"});
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });
        emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 123, Name = "Saket" });

        EmpEqualityComparer eqi = new EmpEqualityComparer();

        var employees = (from e in emp
                         select new Employee { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name }).Distinct(eqi).ToList();
```

It returns single record.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible...

You need to have the class SemesterModel inherit IEquatable. And override two function Equals and GetHashCode.

```
public class SemestersModel  : IEquatable<SemestersModel >{
public string SemesterID  { get; set; }
public string SemesterText  { get; set; }
public bool Equals(SemestersModel comp)
{
    if (SemesterID == comp.SemesterID && SemesterText == comp.SemesterText)
        return true;
    return false;
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hSemesterID = SemesterID == null ? 0 : SemesterID.GetHashCode();
    int hSemesterText = SemesterText == null ? 0 : SemesterText.GetHashCode();

    return hSemesterID ^ hSemesterText;
}}
```