# C# ToListAsync with distinct names

Tags: c#

Hello I would like to select a list of cities from DB, with no duplicate names.
After researching the issue I have tried multiple combinations using First and Distinct but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Any insight would be great. Below is my code

TABLE

**Cities**

PK Id

Name

IsActive

C#

```
var cities = await Db.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Well what is the problem? Do you still get duplicates? You know, **ALL** the values have to match for it to be distinct

Comment: can you share Db schema

Comment: Yes I still get duplicate object by name. Oh I did not know that. What I need to pass something into the distinct as a parameter to get it ONLY by name?

Comment: have you tried working through the official documentation?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try get only names and then get distinct from them... something like `var cities = await Db.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Select(x=> x.Name).Distinct().ToListAsync();`

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a ton

Comment: @Rye: You can use a group by, [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321013/distinct-in-linq-based-on-only-one-field-of-the-table). The point you need to think about is how do you decide which of the 'other' non distinct values you want? If you only want a list of names: `var cities = (from x in Db.Addresses where x.IsActive select new { x.Name } ).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Hi .. Distinct method does not take any parameters. Either you can create your own extension method which will be a complex logic to compare each object with rest of all in the list or you can use IEquatable interface as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DistinctBy(x=>x.Name)`

```
var cities = await Db.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).DistinctBy(x=>x.Name).ToListAsync();
```

Where `DistincBy`:

```
public static IEnumerable<t> DistinctBy<t>(this IEnumerable<t> list, Func<t, object> propertySelector)
{
    return list.GroupBy(propertySelector).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

Comment: I am going to try this. Appreciate the insight

Comment: @Scott I think you're right, I will edit to include standalone method

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
var cities = await Db.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Select(x=> x.Cities).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```