# Bind DropDown For Searching in List using Mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new in Mvc i have no idea how to implement searching in mvc using dropdown list (IEnumerable)?

IEnumerable

```
  @model IEnumerable<PinkPearl.Models.GenerateTicket_Details>
```

This in my view to bind to the Dropdownlist

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ReportCostumeWise", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{ 
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px;">
         <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-left: 0px; width: 6%;">Costume</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 7%;padding:0PX;">
            @Html.DropDownList("CostumeNameValue", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyCustomCollection as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "CostumeName", "CostumeName"),
                    "Costume", new { @class = "collection", name = "Value", onchange = "CostumeNameFunction()", style = " border-color: #dddddd;width: 113%; padding: 7px; border-radius: 4px;" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 14%;">
            <input type="submit" id="btnsearch" value="Search" class="btn" style="float: left" />


        </div>
    </div>                                   
}
```

Table List

```
<table class="table user-list" style="width: 97%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #c7e6ef;">
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>TicketNo</span></th>

                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px; display: none;"><span>Name</span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;"><span>Bill Date</span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>Quantity</span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>Bill Amount</span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>Refund </span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>Rent Amount</span></th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 130px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px"><span>Costume</span></th>
                                        <th class="text-center" style="min-width: 100px;">SUMMARY</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                       <tr @(item.TotalAmount == Convert.ToDecimal(0) ? " class=\ttr-zero" : string.Empty)>
                                            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNo)</td>

                                            <td style="padding-left: 12px; display: none;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
                                            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArrDate)</td>
                                            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)</td>
                                            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
                                           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Refund)</td>
                                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)</td>
                                             <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CostumeName)</td>
                                            <td style="width: 20%; padding-left: 12px; text-align: center;">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail"  data-id="@item.TicketNo" >
                                                    <span class="fa-stack">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>

                                        <td>@ViewBag.Quantity</td>
                                        <td>@ViewBag.Total</td>
                                        <td>@ViewBag.REFUND</td>
                                        <td>@ViewBag.TotalAmount</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

I was using this in my model

```
  public class GenerateTicket_Details
{
    public List<SelectListItem> RateTable { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TicketNo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string ArrDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrTime { get; set; }
    public string ArrDateTime { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Refund { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public string GenrateBy { get; set; }
    public string cancelby { get; set; }
    public string CancelRefundRemark { get; set; }
    public string canceleddatetime { get; set; }
    public string CostumeName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MasterCostume { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> UserMaster { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
      public ActionResult ReportCostumeWise(string GenrateBy, string TicketNo, string hdnfromdate, string hdntoDate, string CostumeName, FormCollection fr)
    {

        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogOut");
        }
        con.Open();
        List<UserMaster> user = new List<UserMaster>();
        string sql = "select UserId from UserMaster where flag=1 order by ID desc";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            user.Add(new UserMaster() { UseId = dr[0].ToString() });
        }
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        List<GenerateTicket_Details> bk = new List<GenerateTicket_Details>();
        string query = "";
        query += @" select   TicketNo,GenrateBy,ArrDate,sum(CostumeQuantity) As Quantity, sum(CostumeTotalPrice) As Total, sum(ISNULL(RefundAmount,0)) AS REFUND
         ,sum(ISNULL(CostumeTotalPrice,0) - ISNULL(RefundAmount,0)) AS TotalAmount, GenrateBy,CostumeName from GenerateTicket where 1=1 ";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CostumeName))
        {
            query += " and  CostumeName='" + CostumeName + "' ";
        }
        query += @"  Group by GenrateBy,TicketNo,GenrateBy,ArrDate,CostumeName order by TicketNo desc ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            bk.Add(new GenerateTicket_Details() { TicketNo = dr[0].ToString(), name = dr[1].ToString(), ArrDate = dr[2].ToString(), quantity = dr[3].ToString(), Total = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4].ToString()), Refund = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5].ToString()), TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[6].ToString()), GenrateBy = dr[7].ToString(), CostumeName = dr[8].ToString() });
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ViewBag.Quantity = ds.Tables[0].Select().Sum(w => (int)w["Quantity"]);
        ViewBag.TotalAmount = ds.Tables[0].Select().Sum(w => (decimal)w["TotalAmount"]);
        ViewBag.REFUND = ds.Tables[0].Select().Sum(w => (decimal)w["REFUND"]);
        ViewBag.Total = ds.Tables[0].Select().Sum(w => (decimal)w["Total"]);
        ViewBag.MyCustomCollection = bk;
        ViewBag.UseId = user;
        ViewData["hdnnameexcl"] = GenrateBy;
        ViewData["TicketNoexcl"] = TicketNo;
        ViewData["hdnfromdateexcl"] = hdnfromdate;
        ViewData["hdntoDateexcl"] = hdntoDate;
        return View(bk);
    }
```

Every thing is work properly but the problem is "In the list of Costume(searching dropdown) show repeat values" 
What should I do in my view and model for solve this type of problem?
 [image]

Comment: Duplicate records may be because of your query.

Comment: If you have access to the database, match the records you're getting in your Action with the ones executing the same query in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need `CostumeName` field/column to have distinct values (non-duplicate ones), just use `GroupBy` and create another list using first row from each group (similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321013/distinct-in-linq-based-on-only-one-field-of-the-table)):

```
ViewBag.MyCustomCollection = bk.GroupBy(x => x.CostumeName).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Additionally, the dropdown binding is easier by projecting it to a `SelectList` before passing to view, hence no need to define column names in `DropDownList` helper:

```
var costumeList = bk.GroupBy(x => x.CostumeName).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
ViewBag.MyCustomCollection = new SelectList(costumeList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                             {
                                Text = x.ToString(),
                                Value = x.ToString()
                             }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("CostumeNameValue", ViewBag.MyCustomCollection as SelectList, ...)
```