# how to write query and use distinct and order by in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Can you please help me how to write this query in LINQ syntax

```
select distinct machine_id , sample_id  from results where custid = 18
order by sample_id
```

I tried this but not working like the query it shows only machine_id in sample no 1 but I need to select distinct machine_id for each sample

```
 public ActionResult Indexs()
        {
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            var samples = _context.RESULTS.GroupBy(mach => mach.machine_id).Select( x=> x.FirstOrDefault()).Where(x=> x.custid == UserId).ToList();
            return View(samples);
        }
```

I cannot find DistinctBy<> only Distinct available
I tried the solutions in this question but its not cover my case

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321013/distinct-in-linq-based-on-only-one-field-of-the-table
```

please I need your help and thank you in advance

UPDATE :

Still the solution not working as expected and not show all data this is the code I use :

```
var samples = _context.RESULTS.GroupBy(mach => new { mach.machine_id, mach.sample_id }).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(n=> new { n.sample_id,n.program_id }).Where(x => x.custid == UserId).ToList();
```

This is example what I have in RESULTS table and what I need to select:

```
user     sample no 1        machine_id 

 1           1                     4

 1           1                   2026

 1           1                   2030

 1           1                   2046

 1           1                   2053

 1           1                   2058

 1           1                   2061

 1           1                   2080 

 1           1                   2081

 1           1                   2083

 1           1                   2084
```

but with this command it shows only 4 machines:

2080

2081

2083

2084

and I think groupby and firstordefault cause this please how to solve it
and select distinct machine_id from each sample like the SELECT statement
why its very difficult to make simple query in LINQ ?

this is the VIEW code , I dont know if it will be useful :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.RESULT>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Indexs";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<img style="margin-left:250px;" src="~/images/weblogo.png" />
<p style="margin-left:40px;">

    <h3 style="margin-left:100px; font-family:Andalus;text-underline-position:below">
        @Html.Label("Hospital Name :")
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.FirstOrDefault().sys_users.user_full_name)

    </h3>


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr style="background-color:hotpink">

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Program.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sample.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Machine.Machine_name)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Program.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sample.name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Machine.Machine_name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Enter", "Edit", new { id = item.sample_id, programId = item.program_id, custId = item.custid, machineId = item.machine_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Report", "Details", new { id = item.sample_id, programId = item.program_id, custId = item.custid }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Statistics", "Edit", "Statistics", new { programId = item.program_id, hospitalNo = item.custid }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: GroupBy(mach => new {mach.machine_id, mach.sample_id})

Comment: @jdweng thank you sooo much its working last thing please how to order by sample_id ?    :::)))   now its not ordered

Comment: @jdweng thank you so much you saved my life I  found the orderby  please post the result  var samples = _context.RESULTS.GroupBy(mach => new { mach.machine_id, mach.sample_id }).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(n=>n.sample_id).Where(x => x.custid == UserId).ToList();

Comment: _context.RESULTS.OrderBy(x => x.sample_id).GroupBy

Comment: @jdweng can you sir check updated question still not show all machines please check

Comment: I am quite sure that the order of method calls ruins it for you. Try reordering the method calls (specifically placing the `.Where( )` before anything else): `_context.RESULTS.Where( ).GroupBy( ).Select( ).OrderBy( ).ToList();`

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/08wZ2Y) is an example fiddle, illustrating how the order of method calls may affect the filtered results.

Comment: @AstridE. : How can an OrderBy change the filtering?  It make no sense.  The OP says he is getting only 4 rows instead of 11.

Comment: @jdweng It's not about the OrderBy, but the positioning of Where. When you group RESULTS by machine_id and sample_id, there may be several items in each group. When selecting only the first item in each group, the selected item may have user = 2 rather than user = 1, regardless if a similar item with user = 1 actually exists in the group. My theory is that for each { machine_id, sample_id } combination that isnt included in the end result, there exists a similar entry in RESULTS with user != 1 that is found before the entry with user == 1.

Comment: @AstridE. The groups still should be 11.  I think the OP has typo in the code and using the wrong properties.  If removing the WHERE does not show the 11 items then there are other errors.  Still the error has nothing to do with the OrderBy.

Comment: @jdweng _ If removing the WHERE does not show the 11 items then there are other errors._ I agree. I am not addressing that. _Still the error has nothing to do with the OrderBy._ Also, agreed. I consistently refer to the _order of method calls_ in my reasoning, not the _.OrderBy()_ method call. I am trying to point out that placing the .Where() call _before_ the grouping and selection of the first element in each group may result in a different output, depending on the full content of `RESULTS`. Perhaps [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KwNz32) provides a better example.

Comment: @AstridE. : Placing the WHERE should not make a differences in this case.  The OP wants 11 items and the 11 items are in the database.  Yes in some cases placement of WHERE can affect the results but not in this case.  Your comments are confusing and not helping to get at the root cause.

Comment: @jdweng I believe that the database table contains more entries than those displayed in the question post. _If that assumption is correct_, the placing of `.Where()` could definitely make a difference, seeing as entries in the database table that are not displayed here may be associated with the identical pair of `{ sample_id, machine_id }`, but with different users.

Comment: @AstridE. : I agree it can contain more, but it should contain at least the 11 rows. If the filtering is removing some of the 11 rows than the where is wrong.  My only comment to you was the ORDERBY had nothing to do with issue.

Comment: @jdweng I think we are still talking past each other. A few hours ago, I added an answer where I try to explain my thoughts about the potential issue. You may disagree with it, and that's fine. Either way, I don't see the benefit of us discussing this further under the question post, so I will leave this as my final comment on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have typos in the query or using wrong properties.  Below is getting correct results.  I split the orderby into two pieces.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Context _context = new Context()
            {
                RESULTS = new List<RESULTS>()
                {
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 4 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2026 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2024 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2038 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2046 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2053 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2058 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2061 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2080 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2081 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2083 },
                    new RESULTS() { user = 1, sample_id = 1, machine_id = 2684 }

                }
            };
            int UserId = 1;
            var samples = _context.RESULTS.GroupBy(mach => new { mach.machine_id, mach.sample_id }).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(n =>  n.sample_id ).ThenBy(x => x.machine_id).Where(x => x.user == UserId).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<RESULTS> RESULTS { get; set; }
    }
    public class RESULTS
    {
        public int user { get; set; }
        public int sample_id { get; set; }
        public int machine_id { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I tried this query   
select distinct machine_id , sample_id , custid from results where 
custid = 30 and sample_id = 1 order by sample_id           and i take the code you did this is the controller :       public ActionResult Indexs()
        {
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            var samples = _context.RESULTS.GroupBy(mach => new { mach.machine_id, mach.sample_id }).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(n => n.sample_id).ThenBy(x => x.machine_id).Where(x => x.custid == UserId).ToList();
            return View(samples);
        }

Comment: when I run the query in the database its working and return data for this user but in the system its not return any thing , some users its return some , I confused and very sad I have to solve this error today

Comment: Remove the WHERE from query and see results.   When you do not get same results as database you either are connected to the wrong database (check connection string) or the filter (WHERE) is wrong.

Comment: The RESULTS table in the database includes so many columns not only these columns maybe this will affect ?

Comment: can you please see this question I changed everything but still no luck please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849109/why-the-database-view-show-data-correct-but-when-i-called-it-in-controller-show

Comment: Do you see all the 12 rows that you expect using "Select *".   The only reason you will not get right data is if the WHERE is not correct.  Either x.custid  or UserId is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example using distinctBy

```
Obj obj0 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = "name1" };
Obj obj1 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = "name2" };
Obj obj2 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = "name1" };
Obj obj3 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = "name2" };
Obj obj4 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = "name4" };
Obj obj5 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = "name2" };
Obj obj6 = new() { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = "name3" };

List<Obj> list = new() { obj0,obj1,obj2, obj3 , obj4 , obj5 , obj6};

var result = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).DistinctBy(p => new{p.SimpleId, p.Name}).OrderBy(o => o.Id);
Console.WriteLine( "liste count " + list.Count);
int n = 0;
foreach (Obj obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(++ n + " " +obj);
}
record Obj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SimpleId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

result display

```
liste count 7
1 Obj { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = name1 }
2 Obj { Id = 1, SimpleId = 1, Name = name2 }
3 Obj { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = name4 }
4 Obj { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = name2 }
5 Obj { Id = 1, SimpleId = 2, Name = name3 }
```

you see all duplicates are deleted

Comment: I tried your answer but its not show DistinctBy only Distinct ?

Comment: @MarwanAbu [.DistinctBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) was first introduced in .NET 6. If you are using an earlier version of .NET, it will unfortunately not be available.

Comment: I am using 4.5.2 I will change it to .NET 6  , can you please check the updated question still not working

Answer (score 1):

I find that your question post (as it currently stands) leaves some parts open to interpretation.

My understanding is that the displayed `RESULTS` selection

```
user_id  sample_id   machine_id
1        1           4
1        1           2026
1        1           2030
1        1           2046
1        1           2053
1        1           2058
1        1           2061
1        1           2080
1        1           2081
1        1           2083
1        1           2084
```

is in fact the selection you get when executing

> **select distinct** user_id, sample_id, machine_id
> **from** results
> **where** user_id = 1
> **order by** sample_id

, whereas the `RESULTS` table in your database may contain *more* entries than the 11 that are displayed.

Is that a correct assumption?

*(If no, please inform me and I will delete this answer.)*

If so, I believe that there may be entries in the `RESULTS` table where `{ sample_id, machine_id }` are equal, but where `user_id` differ.

As an example, `RESULTS` may contain *two* entries where `sample_id == 1` and `machine_id == 4`:

```
user_id  sample_id   machine_id
-------------------------------
2        1           4
1        1           4
...      ...         ...          // other entries
```

When grouping these two entries by `{ sample_id, machine_id }`, you will get one grouping containing two elements:

```
Key:
    { 1, 4 }
Elements:
    { 2, 1, 4 },
    { 1, 1, 4 }
```

Selecting the *first* element in that grouping will give you

```
{ 2, 1, 4 }
```

, simply because `{ 2, 1, 4 }` appeared *before* `{ 1, 1, 4 }` in the table. We basically disregarded the database table entry `{ 1, 1, 4 }` before even getting to the `.Where()` statement.

Now, by using `.Where()` to get only the elements that are associated with `user_id == 1`, the element `{ 2, 1, 4 }` will be *excluded*, seeing as `user_id == 2`.

---

My suggestion is therefore to change the order of method calls, so that `.Where()` is used *prior to* the grouping and selection of the first group element. A minimal example:

```
var filteredResults = results
    .Where(r => r.user_id == 1) // filtering before grouping
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.machine_id, r.sample_id })
    .Select(r => r.First());
```

When doing this, the grouping will only be based on entries where `userId == 1`, and therefore, no entry associated with `user_id == 1` will be "lost" in the stage of selecting the first element in each grouping.

[This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KwNz32) may help in displaying the difference regarding the order of method calls.