# Why the database view show data correct but when I called it in controller show different result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I changed the project design and created database view :

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[samplesList] 
AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        results.machine_id, 
        sample_id, 
        program_id, 
        Machines.Machine_id AS 'ID', 
        custid,
        sys_users.user_full_name AS 'HospitalName',
        Programs.name AS 'ProgramName', 
        machines.Machine_name AS 'MachineName', 
        samples.name AS 'SampleName'
    FROM 
        results 
    INNER JOIN
        programs ON RESULTS.program_id = Programs.id
    INNER JOIN
        Machines ON RESULTS.machine_id = Machines.Machine_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys_users ON RESULTS.custid = sys_users.user_id 
    INNER JOIN
        samples ON RESULTS.sample_id = samples.id
```

This is the result in the database :

[image]

See the screenshot - it shows the correct data sample no 1, sample no 2, sample no 3 and their machines are correct.

But in the controller when I link the view with the controller its not show same result from the database this is the controller code :

```
public ActionResult Indexs()
{
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);

    var samples = _context.samplesLists
                          .Where(x=> x.custid == UserId).ToList();

    return View(samples);
}
```

This is the model :

```
namespace warehouse.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class samplesList
    {
        public Nullable<int> machine_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> sample_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> program_id { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> custid { get; set; }
        public string HospitalName { get; set; }
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public string MachineName { get; set; }
        public string SampleName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally the surprise this is the output for same view in the site :

All data appears as "sample no 1":

[image]

This is the view markup:

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.samplesList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Indexs";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<img style="margin-left:250px;" src="~/images/weblogo.png" />
<p style="margin-left:40px;">

    @*<h3 style="margin-left:100px; font-family:Andalus;text-underline-position:below">
        @Html.Label("Hospital Name :")
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.FirstOrDefault().)

    </h3>*@


    <table class="table table-bordered">

      
        <tr style="background-color:hotpink">

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProgramName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SampleName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MachineName)
            </th>
            @*<th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>*@
          
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SampleName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineName)
                </td>
```

Please I need your help what happening why all solutions not working and what I need to change ?

Comment: EF supports logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception enable it and check if the query that is run is the one you expect. If you  set a break point on the View(samples) call, what is in the samples list? Is that correct? If it isn't you have a database issue and we don't need the asp.net mvc stuff. If the samples list is correct then we don't need the database stuff. My bets are on a database problem. Are you sure that sql view is also altered in the database that is used during debugging?

Comment: @rene ok thank you I will check break point and the view same not changed I checked multiple time and add and remove it also from EF multiple times but same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF has its share of troubles with views - because views typically don't have a defined primary key, which is crucial for EF to detect which data has already been loaded (and which hasn't).

What happens here is: since there's no primary key for your view, EF will just use *all non-nullable columns* from the view as a "substitute" PK.

And when EF reads the data, it will go:

- read the row
- check the primary key (or the "substitute" PK in this case)
- if it has *already read* a row with that PK - it just duplicates that row that it already has - it will **disregard** any non-PK columns actually read from the view!

So in your case, once it's read a first row with the "substitute" PK, any further rows with those same values will just get the already read values - no matter what's stored in the database!

**SOLUTION:** EF needs a proper primary key to **uniquely identify** each individual row of data.

One solution is to add every single PK of all the underlying tables, and make sure those are marked as "non-nullable" in your model class. Another solution might be to add a custom `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (....)` column as an "artificial" dummy PK which gives each row a unique value - so that no two rows being read from the view are considered identical.

Comment: Thank you sir you mean first solution to add the primary keys from the joined tables to the view and try ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in different way as marc_s said there is different activity in database views and primary keys not deal like the tables primary key

What I did :

I created new TABLE (MASTER_RESULTS) and inserted the data I need without duplicate and created the controller and view based on this master table .