# LINQ: List of Unique Names

Tags: c#, linq

(Simplified)

I have a list of full name Strings. The first **6** characters are the **first name** always.

```
List<string>()
  fredXXsmith
  aliceXFloor
  billXXjohnson
  fredXXperterson
```

How can I get the list of unique first names from these strings in LINQ?

```
  fredXX 
  aliceX 
  billXX
```

Comment: This might be a bit old, but it could still be useful: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1300116/1026130](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1300116/1026130)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to project the full names to the substrings, and then use `Distinct`:

```
var firstNames = names.Select(x => x.Substring(0, 6))
                      .Distinct();
```

This is assuming (given your example) that you *always* have at least 6 characters (padded with X). Add a `ToList` call to the end of the chain if you want a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
names.Select(fullName => fullName.Substring(0, 6)).Distinct();
```

`Substring` gets you the first six characters, and `Distinct` gives you unique results.

Answer (score 2):

```
names.Select(x => x.Substring(0,6)).Distinct()
```