# Select distinct from single column in lightswitch

Tags: sql, select, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to execute this SQL query inside lightswitch:

```
Select distinct [columnName] from [table]
```

The query window only has **Filter**, **Sort**, and **Parameters**

I have arrived on the DataService.cs file where I can manualy edit the queries, but im stuck here:

```
    partial void QueryName_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<ServiceUser> query)
    {
        query = query.Distinct();
    }
```

This selects the whole table. I want the distinct values of only one column.
Note that I can add a view to the database and update it as an entity but thats not what I'm looking for..

Comment: Why you don't try to use .GroupBy(i=> i.ColumnName)?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda