# Removed object property duplication from list

Tags: c#

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }    
    public string protocol { get; set; }    
    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a list of my object:

```
List<Capture> list = db.Captures.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
```

What i want to do is get new list that removed the duplicate `protocol`.
for example if i have in my list 10 object and 9 of them with protocol `DOC` and 1 `PDF` i want a new list with only 2 object `DOC` and 1 `PDF`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, depending on how you generally want to use the instances of your `MyObject` class.

The easiest one is implementing the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so as to compare only the `protocol` fields:

```
public class MyObject : IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public sealed override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as MyObject);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.protocol == other.protocol;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return protocol.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can then call [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before converting your enumerable into a list.

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`Distinct` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The equality comparer would have to be an object that determines equality based on your criteria, in the case described in the question, by looking at the `protocol` field:

```
public class MyObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        if (x == null) {
            return y == null;
        } else {
            if (y == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return x.protocol == y.protocol;
            }
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        return obj.protocol.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how i am use it in my list ? (i am new developer...)

Comment: @user979033: `Distinct` is an extension method like `Where` and `ToList` - instead of ending your expression with `.ToList();`, have it end with `.Distinct().ToList();`.

Comment: Thats what i did and the list remained the same size

Comment: @user979033: Can you show how you implemented `Equals` and called `Distinct` in an appended *EDIT* section at the end of your question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the simplest approach:  The following will group `list` by `protocol` and then get the first instance from each group to produce an enumerable with one instance of each type of `protocol`.

```
list.GroupBy(x => protocol, x => x)
    .SelectMany(k, v => v.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct protocols, loop on them and subselect only first object of the same protocol - thus you'll get the list you need.

Comment: Why the restriction to `count > 1`? The question says nothing about that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper " get new list that removed the duplicate protocol"

Comment: `GroupBy` already produces groups by protocol; the OP can just use the first item of each group (or somehow compile one item per group in whichever way he/she likes). Putting the grouped items back together into one unidimensional list and removing anything from there with `RemoveRange` seems somewhat nonsensical to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper deleting the first option, getting ahead of myself in rating race :)

Comment: Actually, I didn't think the first option with `GroupBy` was that bad, *if* you use it to do something with all of the grouped items. Such as, creating a "mixed item" that represents all items of the given protocol, somehow. (I'm not sure the OP has considered whether just taking *any* one item of each protocol will do.)

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `Distinct`, or use the same solution provided here:

[Distinct() with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda)