# Grouping orders by category in MVC4 View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

In our MVC4 application my database has an Orders table, a Products table and a Category table. Every Order has a product (plus quantity) in a foreign key relationship and the product belongs to a category with a foreign key.

So Order has an OrderId, ProductId (FK to Product), a data plus a quantity and Product has a ProductId, Name, and a CategoryId (FK to Category) and Category has a CategoryId and a Name.

Now we want to make a "shopping list" which displays the categories that are ordered during the day and display the products below the category name.

The query below based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda) does just that (except for checking the date):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
            .Include(o => o.Product.Category)
            .GroupBy(o => o.Product.Category.Name)
            .Select(cat => cat.FirstOrDefault());

        return View(orders.ToList());
    }
```

In our view I can display the different categories by doing:

```
@foreach (var cat in Model) {
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(catName=> cat.Product.Category.Name)
           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
}
```

The next step is to display the different ordered products and quantities below this in the for-loop. So that it will look like this, e.g.,:

```
*Fruit*
Banana x2
Apple x1

*Drinks*
Milk x1
```

I am struggling with this and was wondering how to do it. I hope someone can give me some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, we solved the problem by making a tuple:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
        .GroupBy(o => o.Product.Category.Name)
        .Select(cat => cat.FirstOrDefault());

    var products = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product);

    return View(Tuple.Create(orders.ToList(), products.ToList()));
}
```

and in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Item1) {
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(catName => item.Product.Category.Name)
               <br />

               @foreach (var product in Model.Item2)
               {
                  if (product.Product.Category.Name == item.Product.Category.Name)
                  {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(productName => product.Product.Name)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(productName => product.Quantity) <br />
                  }
               }

           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
}
```

Looks a bit crappy as of now but it works!