# Lambda expression + Dictionary: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have something like this:

```
var result = new MyList()
{
    Items = new List<Item>(),
    ...
}
```

where each Item has, among others, an `itemType` property, I need a `Dictionary<itemType, count>` which returns the count of each `itemType` in my list.
I did this:

```
var res = new Dictionary<itemType, int>();
res = result.Items.ToDictionary(a => a.itemType,
                                a=> result.Items.Count(i => i.itemType== a.itemType));}
```

But I'm getting this error "**An item with the same key has already been added**" beacuse of course there are several items with the same type in my list, how can I do a group by or a distinct???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten it, but anyway:

```
var groups = result.Items.GroupBy(r => r.itemType).Select(g => new { id = g.Key, count = g.Count() });
var res = new Dictionary<itemType, int>();
res = groups.ToDictionary(a => a.id, a=>a.count);
```