# How to use a lambda expression in Enumerable.Distinct()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an enumerable of objects for which I need to specify equality.

```
var values = list.Distinct();
```

Is there a way to use lambda expression in Enumerable.Distinct() or some equivalent workaround?

```
var values = list.Distinct((value1, value2) => value1.Id == value2.Id);
```

Comment: Where does value1 and value2 come?

Comment: Does this help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda?rq=1

Comment: Ah, reading that question, those are the values to compare to find the distinct.

Comment: you must have a `IEqualityComparer` class in order to `Distinct` elements.

Comment: @Patrick It works! Problem solved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but you need to create a class that implements IEqualityComparer.  Then you use [Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No, you cant</strike>. You can, in the way that @Hogan says in his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22815177/806975)

Also, you can use `Select` before `Distinct`, if you want to make distinct for a specific field.

```
list.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct();
```

However, this will return only the selected value (`Id`).

Based on the question [referred by @Patrick in his comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813541/how-to-use-a-lambda-expression-in-enumerable-distinct#comment34791979_22813541) ([Distinct() with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda)), and trying to add something to it, you can do an extension method to make what you want to do:

```
namespace MyProject.MyLinqExtensions
{
    public static class MyLinqExtensions
    {
        public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> list, System.Func<TSource, TKey> expr)
        {
            return list.GroupBy(expr).Select(x => x.First());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it this way:

```
list.DistinctBy(x => x.Id)
```

Just remember to import the namespace in the class where you want to use it: `using MyProject.MyLinqExtensions;`