# How can I show a subselection in a second combobox for each ListItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

In my application I have items which can contain a `Town`. Each `Town` consists of a `PostalCode` and a `Name`, e.g.

```
<Code>
  <Row
    Code="1234"
    Name="County A - Town A"
  />
</Code>
<Code>
  <Row
    Code="1234"
    Name="County A - Town B"
  />
</Code>
<Code>
  <Row
    Code="1235"
    Name="County B"
  />
</Code>
<Code>
  <Row
    Code="1236"
    Name="County C"
  />
</Code>
```

The `PostalCode` can be repeated for several towns.

In my UI I show the selection as follows:
[image]

But this is confusing for the user, as there are multiple similar `PostalCode`s.

Is there a way to group the `Town`s by each distinct `PostalCode` and filter the second `ComboBox` with the filtered `Name`s?

An important remark is that a `Town` is a property of an `Item`, which is my `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`.

**Edit**

I've changed my code as suggested to the following:

**XAML**

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="PostalCodeComboBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.DistinctPostalCodeTowns}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Address.Town}" SelectionChanged="PostalCodeComboBox_SelectionChanged" />

    <ComboBox x:Name="NameComboBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.TownsByCode}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Address.Town}" SelectionChanged="NameComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        VivendaContext = new DataModels.VivendaContext();
        //Call a ToList to load the data into the .Local property.
        VivendaContext.Premises.ToList();
        Premises = VivendaContext.Premises.Local;
        Towns = VivendaContext.Towns.ToList();
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/1300116/1653998
        DistinctPostalCodeTowns = VivendaContext.Towns.DistinctBy(t => t.PostalCode).ToList();
        TownsByCode = Towns;
    }

    internal void PostalCodeComboBox_SelectionChanged(ComboBox sender)
    {
        if(sender.SelectedItem as Town != null)
        {
            TownsByCode = Towns.Where(t => t.PostalCode == (sender.SelectedItem as Town).PostalCode).ToList();
        } else
        {
            TownsByCode = Towns;
        }
    }
```

And this works wonderfully when I select a `PostalCode`, it filters the towns with that postalcode. But when I load my data (or select a `Town` via its `Name`), **I only get to see a `PostalCode` when it's the first town with that postalcode.**

I know this is a side-effect of the `DistinctBy` and the fact that not all `Town` Entities are available in my `DistinctPostalCodeTowns` property.

My first thought was to use the `SelectionChanged` event on my `NameComboBox`, to select the right `Town` via its postalcode, but as the `PostalCodeComboBox` is repeated for each item, I can't access it.

Any suggestions on how to get my `PostalCodeComboBox` selecting the right `PostalCode` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define two collections. First will contain distinct codes and the second will dynamically fill Towns by code for every SelectionChanged event int Codes-listbox.

```
public string CurrentCode {get;set;}
public List<string> AllCodes {get;set;}
public List<Town> TownsByCode {get {return AllTowns.Where(r=>Code == CurrentCode).ToList();}}
public List<Town> AllTowns {get;set;}
```

XAML

```
// Codes selector
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCode, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="Binding AllCodes">
</ListBox>

// Towns by code
<ListBox ItemsSource="Binding TownsByCode" />
```

Also in `CurrentCode` setter you must notify that `TownsByCode` property is changed.

Comment: Where do I define these extra properties? On my viewmodel? On my entity that contains a `Town`? Wont the second combobox still be filtered when I select a different item and want to change the town of that new item?

Comment: These properties should be defined in ViewModel. When you select a different code, tows list be changed.

Comment: How can I use `CurrentCode` for each item? Suppose I have a list of 5 items, each with a different `PostalCode`?

Comment: List of codes will contain 5 entries. `CurrentCode` will represent only one code which is selected in the list. Care, if nothing is selected, `CurrentCode` can be null.

Comment: I've edited my question with your suggestions. Would you care to look at it again?

Comment: When make assign `TownsByCode = [...]` you must notify that property `TownsByCode` was changed.

Comment: That happens. I think my record is not selected because the `DistinctBy` yields the first `Town` with that `PostalCode`, and the currently selected `Town` is not the same record, but only has the same `PostalCode`.

Comment: You should bind `SelectedItem` of `PostalCodeComboBox` to a separate variable `public string CurrentCode {get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

first if you want to define the name in XAML you should define it by this way :

```
<ComboBox Name="combo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

and you can edit it in C# code by this way:

```
combo.Items.Add("Hello");
combo.Items.Add("Combo");
combo.Items.Add("Box");
```

But if you want to write the whole code in C# :

```
ComboBox combo2 = new ComboBox();
combo2.Items.Add("I`m");
combo2.Items.Add("Mohamed");
combo2.Items.Add("Slama :p");
combo2.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 0, 0);
combo2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
      //add to canvas
canv.Children.Add(combo2);
```

I hope it will be useful