# Selecting from list based on multiple unique fields

Tags: c#, linq, list, select

I currently have a list containing items which have fields: "name, description, source, title, ...". I want to dump a list from this, but solely unique based on two keys, the name and description. Basically, I don't want items from the list with the same name and the same description, but if they have different names and the same description, then it's fine.

I looked up that using

```
 list.select(x => x.Name).Distinct()
```

would give me a list with distinct name, but stacking them would violate having one of the unique keys different, and one the same.

I also took a look into hash sets, but I'm completely confused on how that works.

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for all distinct name/description combinations:

```
list.Select(x => new {x.Name, x.Description}).Distinct();
```

Comment: However we don't know if the OP wants also the other informations present in its items.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the following example taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda):

```
IEnumerable<Person> filteredList = originalList
  .GroupBy(person => person.Name)
  .Select(group => group.First());
```

Or use [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) NuGet available [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)

Comment: Why copy/pasting from another answer? Just close as duplicate or post a comment.

Comment: This answer is adapted to the OPs question, the link to the other answer is clearly included here also an alternative solution is provided so I do not believe posting a comment would be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry but I stand on my opinion. If you think that the link solves the problem with all the answers present there then it is a duplicate. If you think not, then a comment is enough. Just changing  a variable name doesn't make this a substantial different answer. .

Comment: I think you are missing the point :-) Please read the answer and my previous comments fully.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueData = list.Select(x => new
            {
                UniqueKey = x.Name + " " + x.Description,
                Data = x,
            }).GroupBy(x => x.UniqueKey)
                .Select(g => g.First().Data)
                .ToList();
```

*You should probably use some unique/special character/string instead of " " to make sure UniqueKey is really unique.*