# C# ObservableCollection<T> Distinct not as expected

Tags: c#, unique, distinct, observablecollection

From what I've read on Stack and other resources, this should yield a distinct collection of objects (essentially unique), however, that's not what I'm observing as a result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ObservableCollection<CompanySummary> companies = 
   new ObservableCollection<CompanySummary>(DispatchListOriginal.Select(
   x => new CompanySummary { CompanyName = x.CompanyName, CompanyId = x.CompanyId })
   .Distinct());
```

(all of the above is on one line)

I've also tried this:

```
ObservableCollection<CompanySummary> companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanySummary>(DispatchListOriginal.Select(x => new CompanySummary { CompanyName = x.CompanyName, CompanyId = x.CompanyId }));
CompanyList = new ObservableCollection<CompanySummary>(companies.Distinct());
```

The result in both cases is a collection of `CompanySummary` objects however, there are duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct() with lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Distinct` uses the `Equals` method.
Make sure that `CompanySummary.Equals` does what it should do.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the insight, I understand now. will accept when stack allows :]