# construct comma separated string from "name" property of objects stored in a list

Tags: c#

On each looping, I get a value for that field. I want to store all values using comma separated in the variable (String).

```
var result= string.Empty;
foreach (var details in Response)
{
    result+= details.name;
}
```

Example data I am want:

```
result = "abc, de123, 15R2W" ;
```

while current code collapses all into one big string: "abcde12315R2W"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.Join` and some Linq,

```
var result = string.Join(",", details.Select(x => x.name));
```

The `Select` will pull out the `name` string values and `Join` will concatenate them with a comma separating them.

Comment: Do you mean `Response.Select(...`?

Comment: @juharr thank you buddy for timely help :) God bless you for helping me :)

Comment: you can also use `IEnumerable.Aggregate((a,b)=> $"{a}, {b}");`

Comment: one quick question - Is there a way to use only distinct? As I anticipate some repeating values, but not always.

Comment: @Minijack: Too complex for me to understand

Comment: @Learner `var result = Response.Select(x=>x.name).Aggregate((a,b) => a + ", " + b);` is that a bit more clear? :)

Comment: To do distinct look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda

Comment: @Minijack The problem with using `Aggregate` like this is that it's not as efficient because you're doing string concatenation in a loop.  `String.Join` uses a `StringBuilder` thus avoiding the creation of a bunch of intermediate strings.

Comment: @Learner If you just want distinct names then you can put `.Distinct()` after the `Select`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var result = "";
foreach (var details in Response)
{
    result+= details.name + ",";
}
result = result.Substring(0,result.length-1)
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.