# Tell LINQ Distinct which item to return

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, ienumerable

I understand how to do a Distinct() on a IEnumerable and that I have to create an IEqualityComparer for more advanced stuff however is there a way in which you can tell which duplicated item to return?

For example say you have a `List<T>`

```
List<MyClass> test = new List<MyClass>();
test.Add(new MyClass {ID = 1, InnerID = 4});
test.Add(new MyClass {ID = 2, InnerID = 4});
test.Add(new MyClass {ID = 3, InnerID = 14});
test.Add(new MyClass {ID = 4, InnerID = 14});
```

You then do:

```
var distinctItems = test.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());

class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass> {

    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y) {
        return x.InnerID  == y.InnerID;;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClassobj) {
        return obj.InnerID.GetHasCode();
    }
}
```

This code will return the classes with ID 1 and 3.  Is there a way to return the ID matches 2 & 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want distinct then - you want to group your items and select the "maximum" element for them, based on ID:

```
    var distinctItems = test.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());

    var otherItems = test.GroupBy(a => a.InnerID, (innerID, values) => values.OrderBy(b => b.ID).Last());

    var l1 = distinctItems.ToList();
    var l2 = otherItems.ToList();
```

l1 = your current list
l2 = your desired list

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it's actually *guaranteed*, but I'd be very surprised to see the behaviour of `Distinct` change from returning items in the order they occur in the source sequence.

So, if you want particular items, you should order your source sequence that way. For example:

```
items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
     .Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());
```

Note that one alternative to using Distinct with a custom comparer is to use `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
     .DistinctBy(x => x.InnerId);
```

Although you can't guarantee that the normal LINQ to Objects ordering from `Distinct` won't change, I'd be happy to add a guarantee to MoreLINQ :) (It's the only ordering that is sensible anyway, to be honest.)

Yet another alternative would be to use `GroupBy` instead - then for each inner ID you can get *all* the matching items, and go from there.

Comment: +1 But this only works in this particular example since it just happens that ordering the items produces the results the OP wanted.  In other words if the OP wanted the instances where ID=1 and ID=4 this trick wouldn't work.

Comment: the OP didn't really specify what the exact criteria were for picking the right instances - most of us guessed it was the later ID value within each InnerID

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like a job for `Distinct`, this sounds like a job for `Where`.  You want to *filter* the sequence in your case:

```
var ids = new[] { 2, 4 };
var newSeq = test.Where(m => ids.Contains(m.ID));
```

Comment: +1. If you have to discern between the items, then clearly they are *distinct*.

Comment: @Adam: They can be distinct in one aspect but not in another.

Comment: That's exaclty what I am doing but I am having to do it on InnerID so its returning 4 items. I need skip the first instance of it. I think I may look at this approach - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183403/how-to-get-distinct-instance-from-a-list-by-lamba-or-linq/1183877#1183877

Comment: Why did this answer leave me with an image of Distinct and Where as caped superheroes?

Comment: @Jon (Skeet): Then that seems more like a grouping rather than duplicate items.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select one particular of the group of elements that are considered equal using the comparison you use, then you can use `group by`:

```
 var q = from t in tests
         group t by t.InnerID into g
         select g.First(...);
```

In the `select` clause, you'll get a collection of elements that are *equal* and you can select the one specific element you need (e.g. using `First(...)`). You actually don't need to add `Distinct` to the end, because you're already selecting only a single element for each of the groups.

Comment: Once you did the g.Last() how would you then do a select new MyNewClass{...};

Comment: You can write something like `let last = g.Last(...) select new MyNewClass { Sth = last.Whatever }`. The `let` clase allows you to store an immediate result and then you can use it to construct any return type you need in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way.

`Distinct()` is used to find distinct elements. If you're worried about which element to return...then obviously they are not truly identical (and therefore not distinct) and you have a flaw in your design.