# Use a delegate for the equality comparer for LINQ's Distinct()

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a LINQ Distinct() statement that uses my own custom comparer, like this:

```
class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : MyType
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

...

var distincts = bundle.GetAllThings.Distinct(new MyComparer<MySubType>());
```

This is all fine and dandy and works as I want. Out of curiosity, do I need to define my own Comparer, or can I replace it with a delegate? I thought I should be able to do something like this:

```
var distincts = bundle.GetAllThings.Distinct((a,b) => a.Id == b.Id);
```

But this doesn't compile. Is there a neat trick?

Comment: You ought to have a `ReferenceEquals` checks against null on `x` and `y` in your `Equals` implementation.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Distinct takes an IEqualityComparer as the second argument, so you will need an IEqualityComparer. It's not too hard to make a generic one that will take a delegate, though. Of course, this has probably already been implemented in some places, such as MoreLINQ suggested in one of the other answers.

You could implement it something like this:

```
public static class Compare
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TIdentity>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector)
    {
        return source.Distinct(Compare.By(identitySelector));
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<TSource> By<TSource, TIdentity>(Func<TSource, TIdentity> identitySelector)
    {
        return new DelegateComparer<TSource, TIdentity>(identitySelector);
    }

    private class DelegateComparer<T, TIdentity> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector;

        public DelegateComparer(Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector)
        {
            this.identitySelector = identitySelector;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return Equals(identitySelector(x), identitySelector(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return identitySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives you the syntax:

```
source.DistinctBy(a => a.Id);
```

Or, if you feel it's clearer this way:

```
source.Distinct(Compare.By(a => a.Id));
```

Comment: Having done so, you can also write your own extension method that takes a delegate.

Comment: Cool! If someone missed it you can do: source.DistinctBy(x => new { x.A, x.B });

Comment: `TIdentity` should have a `IEquatable<TIdentity>` constraint, and therefore, use the `identitySelector(x).Equals(identitySelector(y))` instead. This is in order to prevent a reference comparison due to generics not inferring the constructed type overloads.

Answer (score 11):

It's unfortunate that `Distinct` doesn't come up with such an overload, so what you have is a good option.

With  [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), you can use the [**`DistinctBy`**](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) operator.

```
var distincts = bundle.GetAllThings.DistinctBy(a => a.Id);
```

You might also want to consider writing a generic `ProjectionEqualityComparer` that can turn the appropriate delegate into an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation, such as the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183403/how-to-get-distinct-instance-from-a-list-by-lamba-or-linq).

Answer (score 7):

Here is my perverse dirty little vanilla C# trick:

```
entities
    .GroupBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First())
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1183877/529618 - you can actually simplify this to a single GroupBy call. It has an overload where you can provide a selector: `entities.GroupBy(e => e.Id, (id, g) => g.First())`

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.gfilter.net/?Post=LINQ-To-Objects-and-Referential-Equality) shows how to create the extension method to be able to use Distinct in the manner you gave.  You'll need to write two `Distinct` extension methods, and one `IEqualityComparer`.

Here's the code, from the site:

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> comparer)
        {           
            return source.Distinct(new DelegateComparer<T>(comparer));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> comparer, Func<T,int> hashMethod)
        {
            return source.Distinct(new DelegateComparer<T>(comparer,hashMethod));
        }
    }

    public class DelegateComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private Func<T, T, bool> _equals;
        private Func<T,int> _getHashCode;

        public DelegateComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals)
        {
            this._equals = equals;
        }

        public DelegateComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T,int> getHashCode)
        {
            this._equals = equals;
            this._getHashCode = getHashCode;
        }

        public bool Equals(T a, T b)
        {
            return _equals(a, b);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T a)
        {
            if (_getHashCode != null)       
                return _getHashCode(a);       
            else
                return a.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it does not follow the rules for GetHashCode and Equals (see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). Any time you use the first overload on a custom class, you are very likely to get incorrect results.  GetHashCode *must* return the same value for two objects when Equals returns true.

Answer (score 2):

As of NET6, a `DistinctBy` extension method was added to the library in System.Linq.

example:

```
Planet[] planets =
{
    Planet.Mercury,
    Planet.Venus,
    Planet.Earth,
    Planet.Mars,
    Planet.Jupiter,
    Planet.Saturn,
    Planet.Uranus,
    Planet.Neptune,
    Planet.Pluto
};

foreach (Planet planet in planets.DistinctBy(p => p.Type))
{
    Console.WriteLine(planet);
}

// This code produces the following output:
//     Planet { Name = Mercury, Type = Rock, OrderFromSun = 1 }
//     Planet { Name = Jupiter, Type = Gas, OrderFromSun = 5 }
//     Planet { Name = Uranus, Type = Liquid, OrderFromSun = 7 }
//     Planet { Name = Pluto, Type = Ice, OrderFromSun = 9 }
```