# How use lambda expression in Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, distinct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq Distinct() use delegate for equality comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607485/linq-distinct-use-delegate-for-equality-comparer)

I need get unique PostViewModel by ID. How do this with lambda expresion?

```
public IEnumerable<PostViewModel> DistinctPosts
{
  get 
  { 
    return Employees
             .SelectMany(e => e.PostList.Posts)
             .Distinct(new PostViewModelComparer())
             .ToList(); 
  }
}
```

comparer:

```
class PostViewModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<PostViewModel>
{
  #region IEqualityComparer<Contact> Members

  public bool Equals(PostViewModel x, PostViewModel y)
  {
    return x.ID.Equals(y.ID);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(PostViewModel obj)
  {
    return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
  }

  #endregion
}
```

sorry, this is dublicate from [Use a delegate for the equality comparer for LINQ's Distinct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607485/linq-distinct-use-delegate-for-equality-comparer)

Comment: It would be great if you showed us what your classes look like and how they relate to one another. From what I understand an employee contains a post list which contains individual PostViewModels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, I have had a similar issue.

Based on [this post](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/05/05/Lambda-IEqualityComparer3cT3e.aspx), I have made this extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                         Func<T, object> keyExtractor)
{
  return source.Distinct(new KeyEqualityComparer<T>(keyExtractor));
}
```

that automatically generates the necessary IEqualityComparer implementation for a given lambda. In your case, that would enable to use something like:

```
return Employees
         .SelectMany(e => e.PostList.Posts)
         .Distinct(postViewModel => postViewModel.ID)
         .ToList();
```