# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<string> ' to 'system.collections.generic.list<entities.tablename>

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried almost all the solutions but of no use.I am unable to get the distinct list of the particular column Priority.Any help greatly appreciated.

```
public List<AlertType> GetAllAlertNames()
        {
            var lstAlertNames = _zyenaDbContext.AlertTypes.Select(x => x.Priority).Distinct().ToList();

            return lstAlertNames;          
        }
```

The following error occurs with return lstAlertNames:

```
cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list string '
 to 'system.collections.generic.list zyenaEntities.AlertType
```

In Model AlertType

```
public string Priority { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Select(x => x.Priority)` is selecting only the `Priority` property (typeof `string`), so you are selecting `List<string>` but your method is returning `List<AlertType>`.

Not sure what you actually want to return but if it is `List<AlertType>` [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has a useful extension method that allows you to do `AlertTypes.DistinctBy(x => x.Priority);`

Comment: Yes, just found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607485/linq-distinct-use-delegate-for-equality-comparer

Comment: yes @stepehen Muecke priority returns string. DistinctBy is not supported by intellisense in entity framework of my application.

Comment: But morelinq won't work on linq to entities, if I'm not wrong. It's dedicated to linq to objects...

Comment: i think i should install morelinq using nuget packages.Let me try n say.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus thanks for ur reply....but how can you distinguish between linq to entities and linq to objects.this is a general question by me to gather info as i dont know the difference.

Comment: @stepehen Muecke: thanks for giving me clarity where the error  lies.I  got he solution.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is i am trying to return only a single property Priority the entity AlertType is unable to cast.

```
public List<string> GetDistinctAlertPriorities()
        {

            var lstAlertNames = _zyenaDbContext.AlertTypes.Select(x => x.Priority).Distinct().ToList();
            return lstAlertNames;

        }
```