# Selecting specific elements from IGrouping using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
}

List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>(){ /* fill with items */ };
```

I need to create a list of Items that meet the following criteria.  From `itemList`, I need to group the items by `Id` and then choose a single item from each group.  The chosen item must be one in which `Selected == true`.  If no item in the group is selected, then any item can be chosen, it doesn't matter, but one must be chosen.

Based on this question: 
[How to get distinct instance from a list by Lambda or LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183403/how-to-get-distinct-instance-from-a-list-by-lamba-or-linq)

I was able to put together the following, which seems to work:

```
var distinctList = itemList.GroupBy(x => x.Id, 
    (key, group) => group.Any(x => x.Selected) ? 
        group.First(x => x.Selected) : group.First());
```

Is there a more efficient or simpler way to achieve this?  I tried `FirstOrDefault()` but couldn't seem to make it do what I needed.  My concern with the efficiency in the above code, is the call to Any().

Comment: Is that not simple enough for you?  Add in a few extra line breaks and/or remove some of the indentation so it fits on the screen better and it looks fine to me.

Comment: @Servy -- I don't understand the down vote? The answers below are simpler and more efficient than my example above.  That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use the [`FirstOrDefault` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358452.aspx), but use the [version that takes a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx), and combine it with the [coalesce operator (`??`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) like so (I've used query syntax here to make it easier):

```
var distinctList =
    from item in itemList
    group item by item.Id into g
    select g.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Selected) ?? g.First();
```

Using the predicate in `FirstOrDefault`, you are picking the first item where the `Selected` property is true.  If there is none, then assuming your type is a reference type (and this is important this to work with `FirstOrDefault`), it will return `null`.

If null is returned, then you'll just return the first item in the group (through the call to [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)), since any item can be returned and a group can't exist *without* items in it (so the call to `First` is always guaranteed to succeed).

Basically, you are applying a selector to the *result* of the grouping, not *while* grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ the fact that `bool` implements `IComparable<bool>`, with `true` being greater than `false`:

```
var distinctList = itemList.GroupBy(x => x.Id,  
    (key, group) => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSelected).First());
```

This requires enumerating and sorting the whole group, though, so your performance will be better if you stick with your approach.

For groups with a selected item, your approach requires iterating the list twice up to the point of the first selected item.  You could remove that duplication like this:

```
var distinctList = itemList.GroupBy(x => x.Id,  
    (key, group) => group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected) ?? group.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521200/1303737)

You can use

```
groupedSource.SelectMany(group => group).Single(item => item.Id == 1)
```