# Distinct elements in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where i display a list of products for a customer. So, there are two kinds of products. So, if customer is registerd to two products, then both the products get displayed. So, I need to display distinct rows. I did this:

```
   var queryProducts = DbContext.CustomerProducts.Where(p => p.Customers_Id ==  
                                            customerID).ToList().Select(r => new
                           {
                               r.Id,
                               r.Products_Id,
                               ProductName = r.Product.Name,
                               ShortName = r.Product.ShortName,
                               Description = r.Product.Description,
                               IsActive = r.Product.IsActive

                           }).Distinct();
```

In this, customerID is the value that i get from dropdownlist. However, it still displays the same row twice. So, can you please let me know how i can display only distinct records.

Comment: On what property you want the Distinct to act on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reasons could be that Distinct when called with no parameter by default compares all the public properties for equality. I suspect your Id is going to be unique. Hence the Distinct is not working for you.

You can try something like

`myCustomerList.GroupBy(product => product.Products_Id).Select(grp => grp.First());`

I found this as answers to

1. [How to get distinct instance from a list by Lambda or LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183403/how-to-get-distinct-instance-from-a-list-by-lambda-or-linq)
2. [Distinct() with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

You can write an implementation of [IEqualityComparer<CustomerProduct>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).  Once you've got that, then you can use this:

```
DbContext.CustomerProducts.Where(p => p.Customers_Id == customerId)
    .ToList()
    .Distinct(new MyComparer())
    .Select(r => new {
    // etc.

public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomerProduct>
{
    // implement **Equals** and **GetHashCode** here
}
```

Note, using this anonymous comparer might work better for you, but it compares all properties in the anonymous type, not just the customer ID as specified in the question.

Comment: Can that be done as an anonymous function without the separate method @dbaseman?

Comment: @dumbledad there isn't :(.  I don't know of any way to do it inline using an anonymous function.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/191013/1001985

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LINQ Select Distinct with Anonymous Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543482/linq-select-distinct-with-anonymous-types)

I'm guessing r.ID is varying between the two products that are the same,  but you have the same Products_Id?