# C# lambda get distinct list of value conditionally

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of users as given below:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "11", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "12", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "12", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "11", City = "Newyork" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "14", City = "Virginia" });
```

Here, I want to get **distinct UserIDs those have different City** by `C# lambda expression`

So, in above case I should get a `List<string>` which will only contains UserId = 11 item because UserId is same but city is different for both the item.

Could you please let me know how would I do this by C# lambda code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @SynerCoder I tried by GroupBy lambda clause, but not succeed.

Comment: @nunu: Please show your code.

Comment: Here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183403/how-to-get-distinct-instance-from-a-list-by-lambda-or-linq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
var result = users.GroupBy(u => u.UserId)
                  .Where(g => g.Select(u => u.City).Distinct().Count() > 1)
                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                  .ToList();
```

should do it.

It takes the {UserId,City} pairs and converts into groups of those pairs indexed by UserId; and then looks for cases where there is more than one city in the group. Finally taking the key from the groups for the result.

Comment: Hi Richard... Now I want to get reverse scenarios... I want to select only those UserIds whose have single or multiple SIMILAR cities... Could you please tell me how would I do it??  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nunu For the single city change the `> 1` condition to `== 1`. For *similar* you'll need to replace the `Distinct` with something that works with whatever you mean by similar (this might be a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) passed to `Enumerable.Distinct`'s overload).  Without a specific definition of similar it is too ambiguous to be more specific.

Comment: Richard do you have an example of how to pass a lambda/anonymous function to Enumerable.Distinct? I.e. like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10476426/575530) but without the separate method.

Comment: @dumbledad Unfortunatelly you cannot. [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb338049.aspx) takes a [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms132151.aspx) rather than a delegate. And there is no way to create an implementation of an interface with a delegate (whether another function or lambda): you have to have a type. It should be possible to create a helper type that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` based on a key extraction delegate without too much difficulty (but too long to write here with the limited formatting options available).

Answer (score 1):

```
from u in users group u.City by u.UserId into grp //group on the id
where grp.Distinct().Count() > 1 // we only want those with more than one distinct city
select grp.Key //we want the key
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely perfect !! Just the different is Lambda and LINQ :) I upvoted too..

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = users.GroupBy(Obj=>new {Obj.UserID,Obj.City}).Distinct();
```