# C# lambda get distinct list of value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of users as given below:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "11", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "12", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "12", City = "London" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "11", City = "Newyork" });
users.Add(new User(){ UserId = "14", City = "Virginia" });
```

Here, I want to **get distinct UserIDs those have similar City** by `C# lambda expression`

So, in above case I should get a `List<string>` which will only contains UserId = 12 item because UserId is same and city is also same for both the item.

Could you please let me know how would I do this by C# lambda code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# lambda get distinct list of value conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176389/c-sharp-lambda-get-distinct-list-of-value-conditionally)

Comment: -1 for first asking [*"I want to get distinct UserIDs those have different City"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176389/c-sharp-lambda-get-distinct-list-of-value-conditionally) and then without showing any effort asking *"I want to get distinct UserIDs those have similar City"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `User` type override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` appropriately? If so, it's as simple as:

```
var duplicated = users.GroupBy(x => x)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.Key.UserId);
```

If not, you should probably consider overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or you *could* just use an anonymous type:

```
var duplicated = users.GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.City })
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.Key.UserId);
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: I was just adding that very thing :)

Comment: The anonymous type trick is really neat. Gotta add that one to my toolbox.